# how to alternate image and text for post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I use Active Storage for adding image to the post. How to create posts where text alternates with pictures? I have post.body and post.pictures.

```
<p><%= @post.title %></p>

<p><%= @post.body %></p>

<p><%= image_tag @post.image %></p>
<br/>
<% @post.pictures.each do |picture|%>
  <p><%= image_tag picture %></p>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

How can I create page where :

text....

image

text....

image

text...

image

Now I can to create the page only:

text...

image

image

image

Comment: So you want the same body for each picture? If so you just need to put `<%= @post.body %>` inside this loop `@post.pictures.each do |picture|`.

Comment: No. I have some text. I want to insert pictures within this text.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html